# Powershell set env variable and get it within one session

Tags: powershell

having a script when the environment variable is set

`$env.Environment = "prod"`

but I would like to get it within one powershell session(from the same script) without restarting it.

Is it possible?

Note:
I want to add the env variable into the registry
`[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Environment ', 'prod', 'Machine')`

Comment: Use `$env:Environment = "prod"` to set the var.